# Puppet can't find class firewall

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-16.04

I have a basic puppet install using this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-puppet-4-on-ubuntu-16-04

When I run `/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --test` on my node I get

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement. Could not find declared class firewall at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:7:1 on node mark-inspiron.

On my node:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module list
```

returns

> /etc/puppetlabs/code/environment/production/modules
>
> ----- puppetlabs-firewall (v1.9.0)

On my puppet master at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:

```
file {'/tmp/it_works.txt':                        # resource type file and filename
  ensure  => present,                             # make sure it exists
  mode    => '0644',                              # file permissions
  content => "It works on ${ipaddress_eth0}!\n",  # Print the eth0 IP fact
}

class { 'firewall': }

resources { 'firewall':
    purge => true,
}

firewall { "051 asterisk-set-rate-limit-register":
    string      => "REGISTER sip:",
    string_algo => "bm",
    dport       => '5060',
    proto       => 'udp',
    recent      => 'set',
    rname       => 'VOIPREGISTER',
    rsource     => 'true';
}
firewall { "052 asterisk-drop-rate-limit-register":
    string      => "REGISTER sip:",
    string_algo => "bm",
    dport       => '5060',
    proto       => 'udp',
    action      => 'drop',
    recent      => 'update',
    rseconds    => '600',
    rhitcount   => '5',
    rname       => 'VOIPREGISTER',
    rsource     => true,
    rttl        => true;
}
```

The file part works but not firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the modules on your master in a master setup with Puppet. They need to be somewhere in your `modulepath`. You can either place it in the modules directory within your `$codedir` (normally `/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules`) or in your directory environment modules directory (likely `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules` in your case since your cited `site.pp` is there). If you defined additional module paths in your `environment.conf`, then you can also place the modules there.

You can install/deploy them with a variety of methods, such as librarian-puppet, r10k, or code-manager (in Enterprise). However, the easiest method for you would be `puppet module install puppetlabs-firewall` on the master. Your Puppet catalog will then find the `firewall` class during compilation.

On a side note, that:

```
resources { 'firewall':
  purge => true,
}
```

will remove any changes to associated firewall configurations (as defined by Puppet's knowledge of the system firewall configuration according to the module's definition of what the resource manages) that are not managed by Puppet. This is nice for eliminating local changes that people make, but it can also have interesting side effects, so be careful.

Comment: When I run puppet module install puppetlabs-firewall, I get The program 'puppet' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install puppet-common then if I install that it breaks my puppetserver install

Comment: systemctl start puppetserver
Job for puppetserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status puppetserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: @markhorrocks The assumption for that command is that Puppet is in your path (which it normally is post-install). You need to provide the full path to Puppet if it is not in your path.

Comment: I installed puppet-common and then installed the module then reinstalled puppetserver and finally copied firewall from /etc/puppet modules to /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules and finally it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @markhorrocks Take a look at this to help with module deployment in the future: https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k.